# light field rendering from camera array

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, glsl

I'm trying to implement something similar to ["Dynamically Reparameterized Light Fields" (Isaksen, McMillan, & Gortler)](http://www.cs.harvard.edu/~sjg/papers/drlf.pdf), where the light field is a series of cameras placed on a plane:

[image: picture is taken from the same paper]

In the paper, it discusses that we can find the corresponding camera and pixels by the following formulation:  MF→D s,t = Ps,t ◦ TF.

The dataset that I'm using doesn't contain any camera parameters or any information regarding what is the distance between the cameras. I just know that they are placed on a plane uniformly. I have a free moving camera and rendering a view quad. So I can get the 3D position of the focal surface but I don't know how to get the (s,t,u,v) parameters from that. As soon as I get these parameters I can render correctly.

Comment: That's an awful lot of unknowns. Is the subject of the photo something with known size?

Comment: @Rook I know the size of the images, there are something similar to this: http://lightfield.stanford.edu/lfs.html 289 views on a 17x17 grid, image resolution 1400x800.

Comment: I was thinking more of the size of the things in the image, because then at least you could start making assumptions about camera and lens geomtry from that. But never mind.